# MSVC++ 2008 text file parsing difference between win7 <-> xp

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, text, fopen

### Work environment

- Windows 7 Ultimate X64 SP1
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (C++)

---

### Text file

My program is parsing pure text-file and running. the next code is that text-file.

```
/*main.txt*/

_function main()
{
    a = 3;      //a is 3
    b = "three";
    c = 4.3;    //automatic typecast
    _outd(b+"3\n");
    _outd(b+a+c);
    d = a/c;
    _outd("\n"+d+"\n"); ///test commantation
    /*//
    comment
    */
}
```

it is a some kind of simple c-styple script that editable at a text editor like notepad.(the contents in this text is not important)

### Code

Text open code.

```
std::wstring wsFileName; //from 

char* sz_FileName = new char[wsFileName.size()+1];
ZeroMemory(sz_FileName,sizeof(char)*(wsFileName.size()+1));

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//for using 'fopen', change wsFileName to ascii
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,0,wsFileName.c_str(),-1,sz_FileName,wsFileName.size(),NULL,NULL);

//open ascii text file
FILE* fp=fopen(sz_FileName,"rt");

std::string ch;
while(!feof(fp))
{
     ch.push_back(fgetc(fp));   //get textfile in ascii
}
```

---

### Problem

Watching `std::string ch` in debugger that:

[image]

That is exactly same i expected result in Windows 7. And the released-execution-file is work fine too. But in Windows XP SP3, it invokes a runtime error.

I dug around a whole night, and finally I found it. I installed the visual studio 2008 sp1 on windows xp sp3 and debugged it.

Watching `std::string ch`:

[image]

I guessed the "newline mark" is the reason why that program crashed in windows xp. and i guessed this problem based 'text encoding between windows 7 and windows xp'. so i make the new script text using windows xp's notepad. and try to parse it. But the windows xp has the same problem. i know that : The problem occurs not only the text file orignated windows 7 but also a new generated text in windows xp. i don't know why the problem happens.

### Question

a pure text file (generated by notepad, editplus, ultraedit, and others...) that generated any windows os(xp & vista & 7), how my program can read that text same result?
i want each user can edit script to control and customize my program in their own OS, using their own simple text editor.

Comment: -1 That post is horribly unreadable. Please fix it; I have done some of the work. The title needs tweaking as well.

Comment: thank you to notice how to writing the headline. and a, b, c.. is not a c++ source code. it is **my program's customized script**. the main issue of this article is 'text parsing'. the script text's contents is not an important part.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't test the char before adding to the string if it contains a unwanted character? E.g. something like:

```
char temp;
while(...)
{
  temp = fgetc(fp);
  if (temp != "\r")
    ch.push_back(temp);
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should work, if the "wrong" char is indeed "\r".

Comment: @Spo1ler No, it depends on how ch is inizialized. Since that wasn't part of the question i haven't answered it. To avoid memory reallocation simply set string size with ch.reserve(filesize), o get the filesize several different approaches are possible. And since a similiar approach was used in the question and the declaration of ch is not shown i simply assumed that this was done.